# Who is the mighty and strong one in Isaiah 28:2?

Tags: isaiah, prophecy

KJV Isaiah 28 : 2

> Behold, the Lord hath a ***mighty and strong one***, which as a tempest of hail and a destroying storm, as a flood of mighty waters overflowing, shall cast down to the earth with the hand.

Who is the mighty and strong one referred to in the above text?

Answer (score 5):

The prophets of the Old Testament are speaking in the first instance to the people of their own time. So what would the prophet have meant consciously?

This verse is part of a passage which is addressed as a warning to the "drunkards of Ephraim". The drunkennness is partly a metaphor, because the prophet is saying in v7 that the priest and the prophet are "reeling with strong drink",  and this is the reason why they "err in vision and stumble in giving judgement". Therefore the Lord will speak to his people instead "by men of strange lips and with an alien tongue" (v11). Then the second half of the chapter turns against the rulers of Jerusalem, so that's a different topic.

In history, the actual destroying storm against Ephraim (=the northern kingdom) was Assyria. Several of Isaiah's prophecies against Ephraim/Samaria/Israel are prompted by the episode in Isaiah ch7 when Pekah the son of Remaliah, who had seized that kingdom, combined his strength with the king of Syria in order to attack Judah and Jerusalem. Ahaz of Judah saved his kingdom then by calling in the Assyrians against his local enemies. It was Tiglath-pileser of Assyria who responded by taking half the kingdom of Israel (including Galilee) into captivity (2 Kings ch16 vv5-9, ch15 vv27-29).

I suggest, then, that the mighty and strong one who is to be the destroying storm against Ephraim is either Tiglath-pileser himself, or his successor Shalmaneser who completed the job by taking the remainder of the kingdom of Israel into exile (2 Kings ch17 vv3-6). The Assyrians are the "men of strange lips and an alien tongue" who are "speaking" God's judgement against Ephraim.

If we want to generalise the message, it is telling us that God will always be able to bring power to bear against those who oppose him and rebel against him. Then the ultimate "mighty and strong one" becomes the Lord Jesus returning in judgement (e.g 2 Thessalonians ch1 vv5-10, Revelation ch19 vv11-16)

Comment: +1 - Good, simple, straight forward answer.  Most commentators agree, eg, Ellicott, Cambridge, JFB, Matthew Poole, Gill, Pulpit, etc.

Comment: +1 A comment in the [NAB from a Catholic perspectives](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/isaiah/28) adds: "* [28:1–6] These verses once constituted an independent oracle against the Northern Kingdom, probably originally spoken during the time between its overthrow by Assyria in 732 and its destruction in 722/721. Isaiah has reused them as an introduction to his oracle against Judah (vv. 7–22), because the leaders of Judah were guilty of the same excesses that had once marked Ephraim’s leadership.